# Resolutions and densities

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing for android and my code runs perfect on nexus or any 3.7 inch device.
If I run it on tablet (7 or 10.1 inch) then the fonts and buttons are very small and the spacing is way too big.

If I run it on 2.7 QVGA then the buttons are too big and overlap.

I am using dp and sp all over the layout so I am surprised it didn't adjust according to different screen size/density. 
Does that mean that I have to wrte the same XML layout in 3 layout folders (large, medium and small) and put my drawable in 3 different density folders?
Or am I amissing something here. Yes I read the "Supporting multiple screen" document and it just loses me with the details (but I did follow the tips of using dp and sp). I am looking for more of a summary/general approach answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dp and sp adjusts according to screen density. Therefore, a screen with 500 dpi and 4000 dpi but with the same SCREEN DIMENTIONS will looks the same.

If they have different screen sizes, it won't fit as you want. If you want to support multiple screen sizes, you'd have to use weights or percentages.

The key is that dp = device independent pixel and it only adjusts according to density, not screen size.

Comment: ohhh so if I want to say this button is to the left of the image by 20dp, then on another screen size this distance can be too short or too long right? I am not sure weights/percentages can be used for such requirement. Can I create another layout with small dp for say smaller screen size

Comment: also how can  I have the font adjusted?

Comment: Correct. The layout should actually be the exact same on the tablet as well - but just have a lot of space to the right/bottom/whatever. As for fonts, I am not exactly sure, but that may need to be changed pragmatically. Also, yes, you can use different layouts for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

In the most cases if you don't make a tablet app, you don't need to make more than one XML layout for different densities/sizes. All you must do is define dimensions with DP and SP as you said.

But is necessary to provide different images in the drawable folder to show one or other in function on screen size/density.

If you put all images in drawable folder (without specify hdi,ldi or mdi) Android will try to adjust the images but not always works fine.

Hope it helps.